# Using moment js to create an array with days of the week and hours of the day?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs

Wondering if there was a way to get momentjs or just use pure javascript to create an array of everyday of the week, and every hour in a day so that I dont have to hardcode it.

So instead of manually doing

```
weekArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday" ....]
```

I'm looking for a way to do something like

```
weekArray = moment.js(week)
```

The same idea for times during the day especially, so I could potentially use different formats.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For weekdays, you could use [moment's weekdays method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/)

```
weekArray = moment.weekdays()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with a locale?

Comment: @ilyo yes, e.g. moment.localeDate('en').weekdays()

Comment: An update to Leo's answer above, it's `moment.localeData('en').weekdays()`

Comment: If name needed in "ddd" format use : moment.weekdaysShort()

Answer (score 8):

I use this solution:

```
var defaultWeekdays = Array.apply(null, Array(7)).map(function (_, i) {
    return moment(i, 'e').startOf('week').isoWeekday(i + 1).format('ddd');
});
```

I got result:

```
["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
```

You can Modify .format(string) to change the days format. E.g 'dddd' will shows:

```
["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

Check [Moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for more advanced format

Comment: This solution is better because it returns the weekdays in ISO order +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little snippet to get the (locale-specific) names of the days of the week from Moment.js:

```
var weekdayNames = Array.apply(null, Array(7)).map(
    function (_, i) {
        return moment(i, 'e').format('dddd');
    });
console.log(weekdayNames);
// Array [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ]
```

If you want the week to start on Monday, replace `moment(i, 'e')` with `moment(i+1, 'e')`.

Comment: A shorter way: `let days = moment.weekdays(); days.push(days.shift()); moment.euweekdays = days;` and then access it with `moment.euweekdays`