# Moment JS array of months

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I'm trying to create an array of months within a selected quarter (current and last).
My code so far, following advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905183/using-moment-js-to-create-an-array-with-days-of-the-week-and-hours-of-the-day) page.

```
var dataQuarter =  Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map(function (_, i) {
        return moment(i, 'e').startOf('quarter').month(i).format('LL');
})

var dataQuarterLast =  Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map(function (_, i) {
        return moment(i, 'e').startOf('quarter').subtract(1, 'quarter').month(i).format('LL');
})
```

This doesn't quite give me the right values inside the array that I'm hoping for.

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Update:

console.log for both variables says:

```
Array(3) [ "January 1, 2020", "February 1, 2020", "March 1, 2020" ]

Array(3) [ "January 1, 2020", "February 1, 2020", "March 1, 2020" ]
```

Comment: Can you give an expected output as an example?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, what values do you want to receive? Currently, you create an empty array and map through their indices (0,1,2) that correspond to the first 3 months in a year. But what is the result you want to get? Current/previous quarter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom function that accepts the date and quarter to perform quarter manipulation for the year from the given date. Each quarter has three months and we're mapping them to an array starting at the first month of the quarter and incrementing month values until we get the following two. An example of it looks like this:

```js
const getMonthsPerQuarter = (date, quarter) => {
    return [0, 1, 2].map(value =>
        date.quarter(quarter)
            .startOf('quarter')
            .add(value, 'months')
            .format('LL')
    );
};

const date = moment('2020-02-27');     // Change the date to any date you want.
const currentQuarter = date.quarter(); // Quarter will be a number between 1 and 4.
const lastQuarter = 4;

const currentQuarterMonths = getMonthsPerQuarter(date, currentQuarter);
const lastQuarterMonths = getMonthsPerQuarter(date, lastQuarter);

console.log(currentQuarterMonths);
console.log(lastQuarterMonths);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you run the snippet you'll see the expected output. In case you want the month name only in the output array, replace `'LL'` with `'MMMM'`.

Comment: Thank you! Slightly modified it to suit my needs and it worked perfectly!